# 301 redirects causing Issue with google maps plugin

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, routes, maps

I have a page in my project that's using the google maps api along with a few simple map markers. I was asked to add 301 redirects to trailing slash for all pages but this seems to have interfered with the map plugin in that it no longer displays the markers when I use 301 routing, without it works fine.

Has anyone come up against this problem before and know of a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra trailing slash was causing the pages to be treated as a directory so instead of the google maps code looking for assets in:

```
Images/Design/map_marker.png
```

It was looking in:

```
/[Page]/Images/Design/map_marker.png
```

Adding a slash before the Images folder resolved it.